# STL in C++ how does it work

Tags: c++

I have very technical question, I was working with C, and now I'm studying C++,
if I have for example this class

```
class Team {
private:
   list<Player> listOfPlayers;
public:
    void addPlayer(string firstName, string lastName, int id) {
        Player newPlayer(string firstName, string lastName, int id);
            listOfPlayers.push_back(Player(string firstName, string lastName, int id));
    }
};
```

this is a declaration of the Player:

```
class Player{
private:
    string strLastName;      
    string strFirstName;     
    int nID;                
public:
    Player(string firstName, string lastName, int id);

};
```

and this is my constructor of Player:

```
Player::Player(string firstName, string lastName, int id){
    nId = id;
    string strFirstName = firstName;
    string strLastName = lastName;
}
```

so my question is when I call function `addPlayer` what exactly is going on with program,

in my constructor of Account do I need to allocate new memory for `new Player`(cause in C I always use malloc) `for strFirstName and strLastName`, or constructor of string of Account and STL do it without me, thanks in advance (if you don't want to answer my question please at least give me some link with information) thanks in advance

Comment: addPlayer() just constructs a Player object on the stack, and then destroys it again - you probably meant to add it to the list I guess.
The constructor for Player isn't doing what you think it is, because you've declare local variables strFirstName, and strLastName instead of just assigning to the member variables of the same name. 
You ought to be using an initialisation list :
Player::Player(string firstName, string lastName, int id) : nId(id), strFirstName(firstName), strLastName(lastName) {}

Comment: Please make sure that the code compiles before you ask what it does. Your current addPlayer implementation should not compiler.

Comment: @Chris Card, good comment. I have to add that it'll be better to pass a `string` as a const reference for performance reasons (both in `addPlayer` and in constructor): `void addPlayer(const string& firstName, const string& lastName, int id)`.

Comment: @Kirill: This is nitpicking / too much info for the OP ... but ... isn't it even better to accept the string per value in the constructor, let the string member default-construct and swap both strings (member<->parameter) ? :-) This would exploit some copy elision capabilities when the argument was an rvalue. I actually hope to see more pass-by-value in the future, given movable types. Cheers! See http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @sellibitze, but in case when the argument is an lvalue or named rvalue you will get unwanted copying. If you want to get an advantage of rvalues you should write two constructors/functions. But this is too much info.

Comment: @Kirill, no unwanted copying. I'll just let the compiler do the copying if necessary. After that I'd just swap the strings whereas you want to specifically invoke the copy ctor in the initialization list. Honestly, I thought that through. Did you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a "correct" implementation of what you have now:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Player
{ 
private: 
    std::string strLastName;       
    std::string strFirstName;      
    int nID;                 
public:
    // You should pass std::strings to functions by const reference.
    // (see Kirill V. Lyadvinsky's comment to OP's question)
    Player(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName, int id); 
};

// What follows after the colon is called the initializer list.
Player::Player(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName, int id)
    : strFirstName(firstName), strLastName(lastName), nID(id) {}

class Team
{ 
private: 
    std::list<Player> listOfPlayers; 
public: 
    void addPlayer(const std::string& firstName,
        const std::string& lastName, int id)
    { 
        // Constructs a Player instance and adds it to the list.
        listOfPlayers.push_back(Player(firstName, lastName, id)); 
    } 
};
```

The `push_back()` function of list allocates a new node that holds the `Player` instance and pointers to other nodes, so you have sort of a "chain" of `Player` instances.

For your question about `Account`, if you have this:

```
class Account
{
private:
    std::string strFirstName;
    std::string strLastName;
};
```

Then you don't need to worry about allocating/freeing memory for the character arrays, for `std::string` will handle that for you.

Comment: D'oh! I missed that. It should compile now.

Answer (score 0):

Go here http://cplusplus.com

In the constructor you should use an inizialisation list.

When calling methodes or assign values to existing variables you mustn't write the type. So you always create new variables.

Example:

```
private:
   list<Player> listOfPlayers;
public:
    void addPlayer(string firstName, string lastName, int id) {
        Player newPlayer(string firstName, string lastName, int id);
    }
}
```

should be

```
private:
   list<Player> listOfPlayers;
public:
    void addPlayer(string firstName, string lastName, int id) {
        Player newPlayer(firstName, lastName, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a +1 if you update addPlayer to actually add a Player object to the list. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the STL string class (std::string).

The string objects are created when Player is created automatically using std::string's default constructor.

When you say: strFirstName = firstName, you are invoking the [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) which replaces in memory the object.  Try not to think about pointers, C++ is about minimizing them.

So you do not need to use malloc when using strFirstName = "blah".

(Btw I don't know what your talking about with "new account")

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to allocate memory in your constructor? The posted code has nothing which makes memory allocation a must.

With standard STL containers like list, string etc, you may or may not want to use custom memory allocators. The typical declaration in your case is `list<Player>`. If you are inserting Player objects inside the list they will be copy-constructed [so do provide a proper copy-constructor if you are dabbling with pointers inside your class]

If you want custom allocation of memory for your list or string, the declaration will be like `list<Player, CustomAllocator>` etc.

The standard provides an allocator that internally uses the global operators that is used as the default one everywhere an allocator is needed. Look into C++ standard, section 20.4.1. The public interface is well described out there.